# Random slowdown i method execution

Tags: android, slowdown

I have a method that does some filtering operations. This method is called in a loop 10000 times. Average execution time of this method is about 3000-5000 nanoseconds (measured with `System.nanoTime()`). But sometimes (5-10 samples out of 10000) it peaks to even 120000 nanoseconds. It never happens on the same sample twice so its not datas fault. What might be the cause of those random slowdowns? I dont think its relevant but code below:

```
private static int lowPassFilter(int data)
{
    long startTime = System.nanoTime();
    int y0 = 0;
    lcount++;
    lx[ln] = lx[ln + 13] = data;
    y0 = (ly1 << 1) - ly2 + lx[ln] - (lx[ln + 6] << 1) + lx[ln + 12];
    ly2 = ly1;
    ly1 = y0;
    y0 >>= 5;
    if(--ln < 0)
        ln = 12;
    long endTime = System.nanoTime();
    long diff=endTime - startTime;
    return(y0);
}
```

Comment: Can you share some code please?

Comment: Are you doing that on the main thread? Any UI operation while you're running that? Do you see any GC message in the logcat?

Answer (score 2):

It's very likely the garbage collector.

Since this is a tight loop called thousands of times, you might actually want to optimize your memory allocation.

There are some tips in the [Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-tips.html), but the basic gist is this:

> Don't do work that you don't need to do.
>
> Don't allocate memory if you can avoid it.

A couple tips that might be useful here:

> Use Static Final For Constants

I see a lot of constants in your code.  If your use static final to store these constants, it is a hint to the GC that they do not need to be as aggressively collected.  So, something like this:

```
static final int zero = 0;
static final int offset0 = 13;
static final int offset1 = 1;
static final int offset2 = 6;
static final int offset3 = 12;
static final int offset4 = 5;
private static int lowPassFilter(int data)
{
    long startTime = System.nanoTime();
    int y0 = zero;
    
    lcount++;
    lx[ln] = lx[ln + offset0] = data;
    y0 = (ly1 << offset1) - ly2 + lx[ln] - (lx[ln + offset2] << 1) + lx[ln + offset3];
    ly2 = ly1;
    ly1 = y0;
    y0 >>= offset4;
    if(--ln < 0)
        ln = offset3;
    long endTime = System.nanoTime();
    long diff=endTime - startTime;
    return(y0);
}
```

Essentially, this causes it to use a "constant" instruction, rather than a field lookup.

> Note: This optimization applies only to primitive types and String constants, not arbitrary reference types. Still, it's good practice to declare constants static final whenever possible.

There's quite a few other tips on the linked page, like avoiding floating point, but I will leave that as an exercise for the reader.  This should help.

Comment: Sorry but literals are constants just like static final fields are. There is no difference for the garbage collector. In fact the GC cares only about objects living on the heap and not primitive constants or variables. There is no object allocation (hint: no `new`... nor method calls) in his tight loop at all.

Comment: @HansKratz are you aware of the differences between the JVM and the DVM?  They handle GC differently.  I'd say following advice on the *Android developer site* is a good strategy :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems most likely that some other process on the device does some heavy lifting in those time intervals and contends with your app for CPU resources.